# Excel - how to convert table headers in rows to columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, transpose

I have a table in this format:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Name | John |
| Age | 19 |
| Color | Green |
| Name | Jane |
| Age | 22 |
| Color | Blue |
| Name | Mike |
| Age | 30 |
| Color | Red |

And I would like to convert it to this format:

| Name | Age | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 19 | Green |
| Jane | 22 | Blue |
| Mike | 30 | Red |

It's like "multiple" transpose, but I didn't find a way to do it.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: You might consider using VBA for this.

Comment: Will be three columns or is that just for the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way, probably not the best as it uses multiple formula:

`=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE($A$1:$A$9))` will return your headings.
`=FILTER($B$1:$B$9,$A$1:$A$9=D$1)` will return the values where your first value (Name) is in cell `D1` from the `Tranpose` formula.  Drag across for the other two columns.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

with Office 365 (dynamic array formula) we can use one formula:

```
=LET(
    fclm,A1:A9,
    sclm,B1:B9,
    lbl,UNIQUE(fclm),
    MAKEARRAY(
        MAX(BYROW(lbl,LAMBDA(z,COUNTA(FILTER(fclm,fclm=z)))))+1,
        ROWS(lbl),
        LAMBDA(y,x,IF(y=1,INDEX(lbl,x),INDEX(FILTER(sclm,fclm=INDEX(lbl,x)),y-1)))))
```

The MAKEARRAY iterates through the rows and columns dictated.  We use INDEXs to get the proper value from the various FILTER and UNIQUE.

[image]

Now this assumes that every group has every label, order inside the group does not matter.  But, the groups must be together.

Comment: To note, this will only work in Microsoft 365 (and not Excel 2021 or lower), since the LAMBDA function is not available in Excel 2021 etc.